# Complexity of deciding if two matrices are permutatively equivalent

Tags: order-theory, computational-complexity

I would like to know if these problems are NP-complete :

1) for two real matrices $A$ and $B$ there exists $P$ and $Q$ permutation matrices, such that $PAQ=B$

2)same question with $A$ and $B$ matrices whose entries are $0$ or $1$

3)same question if $A$ and $B$ are *order matrices*.
What I call *order matrix*, is an $n\times n$  matrix $A$ whose entries are $0$ or $1$, such that there exists an ordered set $(\left\{a_1,a_2...a_n\right\},\leq_A)$ such that $A_{i,j}=1$ iff $a_i\leq_A a_j$.

where $A_{i,j}$ is the coefficient of $A$ that is both on $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) effectively asks to find whether two bipartite graphs are isomorphic. This is equally difficult as recognizing graph isomorphism in general, which is widely suspected to be NP-intermediate.

(1) is the same, but for edge-labeled graphs. It can be reduced to (2) with a quadratic blowup in the size of the problem.

(3) appears to be trivial, unless I'm misunderstanding something: *Any* two "order matrices" of the same size are permutatively equivalent. (Or is $\le_A$ supposed to be a *partial* order?)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! it is exactly what I was expecting : I was not sure of the "equally difficult". For the (3) of course I mean partial order, and I'm now quite convinced from your answer that it is also "equally difficult" than (1) and (2)...Am I correct?

Comment: @jcdornano: Yes, I would expect so, since a graph can be encoded as a partial order -- say, with one element for each vertex _or_ edge, and an edge counting as $\le$ each of its incident vertices. This has a sufficiently regular structure that even if rows and columns are permuted independently we can still reconstruct which rows correspond to which columns.